# On iPhone, Input element with "datepicker" class doesn't span the entire column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to render a datepicker input. I want the input field to span the entire width of the column. On Android (Chrome) it looks fine but on iOS (Safari) the input field is wrapping the text. The image attached shows ios on the left and android on the right. I want ios to show the input field same as what android is showing.

Following is the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0px">
   <div class="date input-group">
    <input type="Date" name="123" class="datepicker form-control" value="2019-09-21" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
     <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Its looking fine on mine chrome browser, which browsers are you using to test? Does this happens even when you reload the page or this occurs only when you switch the view to iPhone from another one.

Comment: @SarojShrestha I am running it on Safari on iPhone. It doesn't make any difference whether I reload it or not

Answer (score 0):

try to add minimum width :

```
<input type="Date" name="123" class="datepicker form-control" value="2019-09-21" autocomplete="off" style="min-width:95%;">
```

Comment: min-width of 95% actually leaves a small margin between the input field and the calendar icon at the end. How did you come up with this magic number? If i set it to 100%, input field overlaps with the calendar icon. Basically i want input field to cover all the available space, which is the column width minus the width of the calendar icon